# Copying array changes data from C_CONTIGUOUS to F_CONTIGUOUS

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Please consider the example below:

```
import numpy as np
pos = np.random.rand(3,1000)
k   = np.random.randint(0,1000,1000) #this is just a random index to walk the array

print pos.flags
```

The previous examples gives:

```
C_CONTIGUOUS : True
F_CONTIGUOUS : False
OWNDATA : True
WRITEABLE : True
ALIGNED : True
UPDATEIFCOPY : False
```

If I copy the array using the previously defined index k I get the following:

```
pos_temp = pos[:,k]
print pos_temp.flags
```

gives:

```
C_CONTIGUOUS : False
F_CONTIGUOUS : True
OWNDATA : False
WRITEABLE : True
ALIGNED : True
UPDATEIFCOPY : False
```

However, If I copy the array in the following way:

```
pos_temp = np.ndarray([3,1000])
pos_temp[:,:] = pos[:,k]
print pos_temp.flags
```

I get:

```
C_CONTIGUOUS : True
F_CONTIGUOUS : False
OWNDATA : True
WRITEABLE : True
ALIGNED : True
UPDATEIFCOPY : False
```

As I expected. This is a little bit annoying when I am passing the arrays to C subroutines. So, my question is the following: Which is the difference between all the previous examples? Why is the behaviour so different in every single case? This is what it is expected, or I am missing something?

Comment: In a nutshell, use `np.ascontiguousarray` (for C-order) or `np.asfortranarray` (for F-order) when you need to guarantee a particular order.  As far as what's going on, C-order is the default, but a common idiom in numpy is to swap axes, apply along the first axes, and swap back.  That's probably what's going on here, albeit at a lower level. The other way of copying casts things to the order of the array they're being assigned to. `np.take` will do the same thing and return a C-order array, but it's still better to call `np.ascontiguousarray` when you need to guarantee the order.